# How to fill + one year date from another textbox current text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I have two textboxes in my vb.net code

```
    <tr>
    <td align="right">
        <b>ActivationReqDT:</b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ActivationReqDTTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ActivationReqDT","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' />                       
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="right">
        <b>DeactivationReqDT:</b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="DeactivationReqDTTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DeactivationReqDT","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want that when I enter date in dd/mm/yyyy in first text box (**ActivationReqDTTextBox**), it will **automatically fill** the second text box (**DeactivationReqDTTextBox**) by adding **plus one year** in above entered date.

please provide your solution with javascript, jquery or vb.net

Thanks.

Best Regards,
MS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what even you want this to fire on, so I'm assuming you may want to fill the next box after first one loses focus. You may adjust that to your needs by changing the event to `keyup`, `change` or whatever.

```
$('#ActivationReqDTTextBox').blur(function () {
    var myDate = new Date(Date.parse($(this).val()));
    myDate.setYear(myDate.getYear() + 1);
    $('#DeactivationReqDTTextBox').val(myDate);
});
```

Couple of things to be aware of:

- you have to make sure that your date format is compatible with the `Date.parse` and if it's not then you need to reformat it before use
- you may want to format the result date as well

`Date.parse` expects MM/DD/YYYY and in your case it's DD/MM/YYYY so you need to swap month with the day. This will do the trick:

```
function reformat(a) {
    return a.substring(3,5) + '/' + a.substring(0,2) + a.substring(5, 10);
}
```

Given that modified code from above should look like that.

```
$('#ActivationReqDTTextBox').blur(function () {
        var myDate = new Date(Date.parse(reformat($(this).val())));
        $('#DeactivationReqDTTextBox').val(myDate.getDate() + '/' + 
            (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (myDate.getYear() + 1));
});
```

#### EDIT:

To make sure the script doesn't fire up when incorrect date is entered in the first field you could do this:

```
$('#ActivationReqDTTextBox').blur(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var regex = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/;
    if (regex.test(value)) {
        var myDate = new Date(Date.parse(reformat(value)));
        $('#DeactivationReqDTTextBox').val(myDate.getDate() + '/' + 
            (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (myDate.getYear() + 1));
    } else {
        alert('invalid date');
        // this will prevent from leaving the input until the date is correct
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

#### EDIT #2:

One more update to the code. This will prevent leading zeros for months and days.

```
$('#ActivationReqDTTextBox').blur(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var regex = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/;
    if (regex.test(value)) {
        var myDate = new Date(Date.parse(reformat(value)));
        var year = myDate.getYear() + 1;
        var month = myDate.getYear() + 1;
        if (month < 10) {
            month = '0' + month;
        }
        var day = myDate.getDate();
        if (day < 10) {
            day = '0' + day;
        }
        $('#DeactivationReqDTTextBox').val(day + '/' + month + '/' + year);
    } else {
        alert('invalid date');
        // this will prevent from leaving the input until the date is correct
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Rayell, Thanks for your reply. I have copied your text in my page. But It is not doing anything. Can you let me know what can be the cause.

Comment: Install firebug and make sure there are no JS errors. You could (IMO should) also validate it against JSLint. Anyway after you are sure there are no errors I would add some `alert` or `console.log` inside the function above to make sure if this code is reached. Then it's step by step debugging until you find out which part of the code causes problems.

Comment: hi Rayell, thanks for your reply. It is working fine. One more functionality required. i.e. if there is no value in first text box then it should not perform this functionality as well as the entered date should in dd/mm/yyyy format.Please help

Comment: OP,please upvote and consider accepting this as the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Hi Rayell, Many Thanks for your answer its working fine but one more problem with the above code is that when I enter the date in format 24/09/2009 in first textbox it returns date in second textbox in format 24/9/110. I am not able to replicate the actual problem why it is not returning correct value. Please help!

Comment: I think it is removing 0 from the date entered in first textbox i.e. if we enter 08/09/2009 it is returning 8/9/2010. but i want it with 0

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about leading zeros for months and days. Check Edit #2 in the answer.